# Retrieve commented value from xml file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

This is my XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">

<serial>PQE43A021640</serial>   <!--    3693    -->
<serial>PQE43E015072</serial>   <!--    3694    -->
<serial>PQE430015069</serial>   <!--    3695    -->
</rss>
```

In above xml file has commented values next to serial node.

I have got serial number using this script

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml");
foreach($xml as $val) { echo $val[0] . "<br>"; }
```

So how can I get that commented values next to serial number?
And also I just want to get that particular line number? those 3 should same line values : e.g (line num : 4 | serial num : PQE430015069 | comented num : 3693 )

Please help,

Comment: I doubt you can, if you insist on sticking with SimpleXML.  (And you should be asking yourself, *why do comments matter so much in the first place?*  If the content matters, it should be anywhere *but* in a comment.)

Comment: can you do it using DOMxml? I have tried and failed lots of time, can you please

Comment: DOMDocument can do pretty much anything.  But it takes some understanding of how the DOM works.  (PHP's implementation mostly conforms to the W3C DOM specs.)

Comment: Hi,
I tried with this, please can you do it using this?
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML(
    '<device>1SE43A021640</device> <!-- 3693 -->
<device>1SE43E015072</device> <!-- 3694 -->
<device>1SE430015069</device> <!-- 3695 -->'
);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment)
{
     
  
 echo $comment->textContent ;
}

Comment: Nope.  For starters, an XML document has a single root element.  Your code there, has three.  Wrap an element around them.

Comment: Hi,
This is my xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
  <appConfig authenticate="true"></appConfig> <!-- Can have values "true" or "false" to activate/deactivate SN verification to launch app-->
<device>1SE43A021640</device> <!-- 3693 -->
<device>1SE43E015072</device> <!-- 3694 -->
<device>1SE430015069</device> <!-- 3695 -->
<device>1SE436012039</device> <!-- 3696 -->
<device>1SE436015066</device> <!-- 3697 -->

  
</rss>

Comment: And have you tried your PHP code from your previous comment, with your real XML?

Comment: How to get values from var_dump ?
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('note.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$lineNo = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query('//serial/following::comment()') as $comment){
    $serial= $xpath->query('//serial', $comment)->item($lineNo)->textContent;
    var_dump ("Line number: ".$lineNo ." Serial number: ".$serial." Comented number: ".$comment->textContent);
    $lineNo++;
}

Comment: ..Huh?  `var_dump` is *output*.  You don't get values from it, if you value your sanity.

Comment: great and just want to say thanks for your time and help, have a great day buddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<serials><serial>KLH4587KIJ</serial><!-- 100001 --><serial>MHF4557PDS</serial><!-- 100002 --></serials>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$lineNo = 0;
foreach ($xpath->query('//serial/following::comment()') as $comment){
    $serial= $xpath->query('//serial', $comment)->item($lineNo)->textContent;
    var_dump ("Line number: ".$lineNo ." Serial number: ".$serial." Comented number: ".$comment->textContent);
    $lineNo++;
}
```